Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'package.json' when building my node app with Docker
I have the following Dockerfile:
FROM centos:7 as builder

RUN yum update -y && \
  yum install -y wget && \
  yum install -y libXcomposite libXdamage libXcursor libXext libXi libXrandr libXScrnSaver libXtst && \
  yum clean all


# create project folder
RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false node && \
  mkdir -p /usr/src/ias-display && \
  chown node:node /usr/src/ias-display
WORKDIR /usr/src/ias-display

# create user node
USER node

# install node
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install 10.15.1

# install Angular CLI
RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh && npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8

# install project requirements
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh && npm install

# copy project files
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200

# test and build project
RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh &&  npm run-script build-prod

# copy compiled files to smaller image
FROM centos:7
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/{my-project}/dist /usr/src/{my-project}/dist
VOLUME /usr/src/{my-project}


When I use my docker-compose file to build it, the following output happens:
docker compose -f {docker-compose-file} build display  
[+] Building 83.3s (16/17)                                                                                                                                                                                        docker:default
 => [display internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.21kB                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [display internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:7                                                                                                                                                         0.5s
 => [display internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 128B                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [display stage-1 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:be65f488b7764ad3638f236b7b515b3678369a5124c47b8d32916d6487418ea4                                                                                    0.0s
 => [display internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 89.06kB                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [display builder  2/12] RUN yum update -y &&   yum install -y wget &&   yum install -y libXcomposite libXdamage libXcursor libXext libXi libXrandr libXScrnSaver libXtst &&   yum clean all                      0.0s
 => CACHED [display builder  3/12] RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false node &&   mkdir -p /usr/src/ias-display &&   chown node:node /usr/src/ias-display                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [display builder  4/12] WORKDIR /usr/src/ias-display                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [display builder  5/12] RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [display builder  6/12] RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install 10.15.1                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [display builder  7/12] RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh && npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [display builder  8/12] COPY --chown=node:node package.json .                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [display builder  9/12] COPY --chown=node:node package-lock.json .                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [display builder 10/12] RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh && npm install                                                                                                                                                    81.9s
 => [display builder 11/12] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                        0.1s 
 => ERROR [display builder 12/12] RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh &&  npm run-script build-prod                                                                                                                                0.6s 
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 > [display builder 12/12] RUN . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh &&  npm run-script build-prod:                                                                                                                                           
0.587 npm ERR! path /usr/src/ias-display/package.json                                                                                                                                                                            
0.587 npm ERR! code EACCES                                                                                                                                                                                                       
0.588 npm ERR! errno -13
0.588 npm ERR! syscall open
0.589 npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/ias-display/package.json'
0.589 npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/ias-display/package.json']
0.589 npm ERR!   stack:
0.589 npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, open \'/usr/src/ias-display/package.json\'',
0.589 npm ERR!   errno: -13,
0.589 npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
0.589 npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
0.589 npm ERR!   path: '/usr/src/ias-display/package.json' }
0.589 npm ERR! 
0.589 npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
0.589 npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
0.589 npm ERR! 
0.589 npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
0.589 npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
0.589 npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
0.592 
0.592 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
0.592 npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2024-04-17T13_48_35_495Z-debug.log
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c . /home/node/.nvm/nvm.sh &&  npm run-script build-prod" did not complete successfully: exit code: 243

I don't understand why it is happening, how can I solve this?
As recommended in another similar question, I tried changing manually permissions of package.json and package-lock.json files by replacing it's lines with these:
COPY --chown=node:node package.json .
COPY --chown=node:node package-lock.json .

But it didn't work, the same problem happens.
I also tried running the docker compose build with the --no-cache option but I obtain the same result.
I added some extra steps to the Dockerfile and these are the results:
#15 [builder 11/16] RUN ls -la /usr/src/ias-display
#15 0.156 total 500
#15 0.156 drwxr-xr-x. 1 node node     31 Apr 18 15:21 .
#15 0.156 drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     25 Apr 18 15:20 ..
#15 0.156 -rw-r-----. 1 node node 507341 Apr 15 14:16 package-lock.json
#15 0.156 -rw-r-----. 1 node node   2158 Apr 15 14:16 package.json
#15 DONE 0.2s

#16 [builder 12/16] RUN whoami
#16 0.154 node
#16 DONE 0.2s

#17 [builder 13/16] RUN id
#17 0.158 uid=1000(node) gid=1000(node) groups=1000(node)
#17 DONE 0.2s



Can you use the Docker Hub node image, rather than trying to convince nvm to work?  Can you run the build sequence as root, moving the USER directive later in the Dockerfile, and leaving most files owned by root and world-readable but not writable?

@DavidMaze I could but this Docker image is not primarily maintained by me, so it would affect the other main maintainers of the Dockerfile. Thus I have to leave it as a centos-based image.

What are the permissions of /usr/src/ias-display/package.json in the container? What user id are the commands running as? Adding some RUN statements that show the output of ls -l ... and id would help answer those questions.

hi @larsks , this is the output of ls -la:
#14 [builder 10/14] RUN ls -la
#14 0.134 total 500
#14 0.134 drwxr-xr-x. 1 node node     31 Apr 17 20:40 .
#14 0.134 drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     25 Apr 17 20:38 ..
#14 0.134 -rw-r-----. 1 node node 507341 Apr 15 14:16 package-lock.json
#14 0.134 -rw-r-----. 1 node node   2158 Apr 15 14:16 package.json
#14 DONE 0.1s

the user running the commands should be the user node

You'll want to edit your question to provide that information, since it's not possible to format things legibly in a comment. I asked for the output of the id command so that we can turn "should be the user node" into "is the user node".

@larsks sorry about that, I edited the question to add the information you were asking
